# AdHoc builds of apps with watch kit extension using diawi

Tags: ios

I have archived my an AdHoc version of my app and using iTunes it installs, without error, on any of the iPhones/apple watches included in the provisioning profile.

However, when I try to install the application from diawi it shows the bundle identifier of my watchkit app, e.g. myapp.com.watctchkitapp and fails installation. When looking in the iPhone logs during installation it fails due to:

> : BundleValidator: Failed bundleIdentifier:
>   com.myapp.watchkitapp does not match expected bundleIdentifier:
>   com.myapp

Clearly they are not going to be the same. Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: Created ticket in diawi support. Waiting for response

Comment: @M.Y. I ended up using another service for distributing my adhoc build with a watch extension. Can’t remember which one but there are a lot identical services as diawi.